# Paypal Kinvey Integration

Tags: ios, swift, paypal, kinvey

I am trying to develop an iOS app with Kinvey as the mBaas and Paypal.

Context:

-Kinvey will store and transmits location data of users
-Paypal Adaptive payments facilitates payments between users and other users as well as between users and the application owner
-One of the 2 stores credit card information (haven't gotten that far yet but I assume Paypal most likely)

Can the Paypal Adaptive Payments API be employed with Kinvey mBaas for a mobile iOS application written in Swift?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, Kinvey doesn’t expose Paypal/Braintree’s (server side) API through backend SDK.

But you should be able to implement it using DLC (Data Link Connector). Please take a look at this: http://devcenter.kinvey.com/rest/guides/datalink#

Thanks, Pranav Kinvey